# Magento 2 Ajax Admin

Tags: magento2, products, ajax, backend

Hi there I'm trying to run a custom module when a product is saved at the moment I have an event listener on the product page and need to send some of the info entered to a controller using ajax.

When making the Ajax call the result is coming back with the current pages HTML on the console. Here is my code any help would be awesome thanks :)

> RelatedProducts/Items/view/adminhtml/templates/js.phtml

```
            function ajax(){
                var name = document.getElementsByName("product[name]")[0].value;
                var type = document.getElementsByName("product[product_category_type]")[0].value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "RelatedProducts_Items/Adminhtml/CustomAjax", 
                    data: { name : name, type : type},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    } 
                });
            }
```

> RelatedProducts/Items/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="RelatedProducts" frontName="RelatedProducts">
            <module name="RelatedProducts_Items"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> RelatedProducts/Items/Controller/Adminhtml/CustomAjax.php

```
namespace RelatedProducts\Items\Controller\Adminhtml;

class CustomAjax extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action


    public function execute()
    {

       echo "testing";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Follow This Step

> app/code/Relatedproducts/Items/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="relatedproducts_items" id="relatedproducts_items">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="RelatedProducts_Items"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/RelatedProducts/Items/view/adminhtml/templates/js.phtml

```
function ajax(){
    var name = document.getElementsByName("product[name]")[0].value;
    var type = document.getElementsByName("product[product_category_type]")[0].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/relatedproducts_items/customajax',
        showLoader: true,
        data: {id:<?php echo $id ?>,p:pincode},
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

> RelatedProducts/Items/Controller/Adminhtml/CustomAjax.php

```
<?php

namespace RelatedProducts\Items\Controller\Adminhtml;

class CustomAjax extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if($this->getRequest()->isAjax()){

            echo "Testing";
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Echo $id is giving me an error on js.phtml so I tried using the data that Im trying to send (data: { name : name, type : type}) This had no luck too same result just consoles the page html and doesn't return Testing

Comment: @NathanielMeyer Please check your frontend router working or not by echo "testing".

Comment: When calling the frontend controller on front end of the website I get testing 
When calling the front end controller from the backend I get the page html again.  This is the same when calling the backend controller.

Comment: Please can you explain where is the admin coming from the url -> url: 'admin/relatedproducts_items/customajax',